# Lifting the monad IO in ConduitT on ResourceT

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm trying to use the function MergeSources in [stm-conduit](https://github.com/cgaebel/stm-conduit/blob/4795394071752085c33b9e17458d041b787dee49/Data/Conduit/TMChan.hs) which has the following signature :

```
mergeSources :: (MonadResource mi, MonadIO mo, MonadUnliftIO mi)
             => [ConduitT () a mi ()] -- ^ The sources to merge.
             -> Int -- ^ The bound of the intermediate channel.
             -> mo (ConduitT () a mi ())
```

I have sources based on IO directly, and I don't know how to move on this mi Monad which I believe ResourceT is the candidate :

so I have sources with the following signature :

```
ConduitT () (Connection,WorkspaceId) IO ()
```

and I would like this signature instead :

```
ConduitT () (Connection,WorkspaceId) (ResourceT IO) ()
```

despite the fact I have no resource to handle in these actions (I have a connection but it's global, that's what they recommend...), I give you an example of the function I want to use

```
streamAllWorkspaceAlreadyCreated :: Connection -> ConduitT () (Connection,WorkspaceId) IO ()
streamAllWorkspaceAlreadyCreated  eventStoreConnection = do
    yield eventStoreConnection
    .| WorkspaceStream.streamAll
    .| WorkspaceStream.discardCorruptedStreams
    .| mapC (\workSpaceId -> (eventStoreConnection,workSpaceId))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `transPipe`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:transPipe

```
transPipe :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> ConduitT i o m r -> ConduitT i o n r

transPipe liftIO :: ConduitT i o IO r -> ConduitT i o (ResourceT IO) r
```